# Can't add Javascript

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, javascript

I'm trying to add a custom Js to my custom template.

**local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
       <reference name="head">
           <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/main.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

I've placed my `.JS` in the `skin` folder. I've repeatedly refreshed my cache. But it won't output the console.log i've placed in it. `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>` is also in `head.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your `.js` in `js` folder in your `skin` folder

Be sure `main.js` **is not** `main.JS`